# Get value from Array using dynamic key in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I have an array as follow.

```
var array:Array = new Array();
array["Circle"] = 1;
array["Rect"] = 2;
```

I wantto read the values by using a variable.

```
var key:String = "Circle";
trace(array[key]);
```

Can anyone guide me how to achieve this. Its not neccessary to go with Array only. I may switch to whichever collection in which this is possible.

Comment: What is it exactly that you would like to achieve.
Do you want some code to loop over all key value pairs of your Map?

Comment: Looks to me that you've already figured it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Object` or `Dictionary`:

```
var obj:Object = new Object();
obj["Circle"] = 1;
obj["Rect"] = 2;

// alternative initialization - only for Object
obj = {Circle: 1, Rect: 2};

for (var key:String in obj)
{
    trace("key:", key, ",", "value:" obj[key]);
}

// output:
// key: Circle , value: 1
// key: Rect , value: 2

for each (var value:Object in obj)
{
    trace(value);
}

// output:
// 1
// 2
```